# My question is about addition of an array of different wrapper classes through java generics

Tags: java, generics

```
public static void doProcess(){
   Integer [] intArray = {2,5,3,8,9};
   returnArray(intArray);
   //Expected output:  27 (sum of all number)
   String[]  strArray =  {"Jack", "Daniel", "Richel"};
   returnArray(strArray);
   //Expected output:  Jack Daniel Richel
   Character[]  charArray = {'A', 'X', 'E'};
   returnArray(charArray);
   //Expected output:  AXE
}
```

I have the above code and the method below which need to complete.

```
private static <E> *** returnArray(E[] value) {
    for(E ele : value) {
        //code for expected output
    }
    //return Expected output
}
```

I need to fill above method as well as fill the return type which is here shown as ***. 
I can't use separate method or introduce any new method.

Comment: What you want this method to do?

Comment: Please spend some time cleaning up your question so it is well-formatted, so we can maybe understand it.

Comment: Does your method have to do totally different things depending on the input type (sum ints, merge strings with space in between and merge chars without space separator)? Good job to the one who came up with this homework task.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to @Lino's answer to suggest a more generic approach: I will assume you want to sum up numbers (be it integers, floats or whatever) and concat anything else (strings, chars, even random objects like `Duration` or `Instant`). It's just that characters will be squashed together, while strings (or anything else, for that matter) will be joined with a space separator.

You can return `Object` or something a bit narrower that fits both numbers and strings (like `Serializable` or `Comparable<?>`); this is hardly useful, but keeps you from returning really random stuff.

Alternatively, you can decide to always return `String` and just return the sum as a string as well (for numbers).

The actual implementation can look pretty neat if you use Java8 streams:

```
// the `E` generic type brings you nothing, as you can't make use of it at compile time,
// so you can simply drop it and go with a mere `Object[]` array, as per @Lino
public static <E> Serializable returnArray(E[] values) {

    // exclude null values if any (note that `E` proves itself useless already):
    final Stream<?> stream = Stream.of(values).filter(Objects::nonNull);

    if (values instanceof Number[]) {
        // you can use mapToDouble and doubleValue, for a more accurate sum
        return stream.map(Number.class::cast).mapToInt(Number::intValue).sum();
    } else {
        // squash characters, but use a space separator for anything else
        final String separator = (values instanceof Character[]) ? "" : " ";
        return stream.map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(separator));
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this answer. I suggest you to use `mapToLong(Number::longValue)` though, so you can include bigger numbers too

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `instanceof`, e.g. you can have a construct like this:

```
public static <E> Object returnArray(E[] value) {
    if(value instanceof String[]) {
        String[] strings = (String[]) value;
        // concat the strings with spaces
    } else if(value instanceof Integer[]) {
        Integer[] ints = (Integer[]) value;
        // sum the integers
    } else if(value instanceof Character[]) {
        Character[] chars = (Character[]) value;
        // concat the characters
    } else {
        // throw exception or handle more cases
    }
}
```

I've deliberatly left out the real code for the different operations as this should just point you into the right direction, (and I won't do your work for you).

The only real tricky thing is the return type. As it can't be `E`. It works with `String`s and `Integer`s, but will break with `Character`s as `'ABC'` is not a valid `char` and thus you can't return it.

Note: using generics and `instanceof` breaks the whole concept of generics. You can aswell just remove it and have a method like this:

```
public static Object returnArray(Object[] value) {
```

Comment: A better approach would be to provide overloads.

Comment: @AndyTurner OP said they can't introduced new methods, but I agree, overloads would be much better

Comment: fair enough, I tuned out reading the question because of its formatting.